# Cannot update WCF service reference for .NET 3.5 web site

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis, .net-3.5

I have a .Net 3.5 website and wcf service.  Both use IIS 7 and I'm working in Visual Studio 2010.  I'm trying to update the service reference but I'm getting the following error:

Failed to update Service Reference 'MyServiceReference.Reference'.
Error: The configuration for the service reference could not be updated due to the following issue: An error occurred executing the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/bindings.(0x80131902)

I can't seem to find anybody with the same error.  Please help or let me know if there is any more information I can provide to help!

Comment: Have you tried removing it completely and then re-adding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: recycle the app pool hosting the service in IIS 7

Thank you for the responses!  A colleague gave me the idea to recycle the app pool hosting the service in IIS 7 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes works if you close VS and try to update again or try right click on the service click on Configure Service Reference

Try to change the url or check the url next click OK

Sometimes works if you add again the service reference.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the Service Reference, then rename back to original name, then try Update Service Reference again.
This worked for me.

Comment: i dont believe but this solution work for me! tnx bro